# Partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} ( {\bf x}-{\bf c})^T A ( {\bf x}-{\bf c})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

How to find the following partial derivative

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} ( {\bf x}-{\bf c})^T A  ( {\bf x}-{\bf c}),
\end{align}

where ${\bf x}$ is a vector of length $n$ and  $A$ is a strictly positive definite matrix, and  ${\bf c}$ is just a fixed vector.

My plan was to re-write it in terms of a double sum and take the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the approach of using the definition of the partial derivative.  In particular,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(\mathbf x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf e_i) - f(\mathbf x)}{t}
$$
where $\mathbf e_i$ denotes the $i$th canonical basis vector.  With that, we have
$$
f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf e_i) = 
([\mathbf x - \mathbf c] + t\mathbf e_i )^TA([\mathbf x - \mathbf c] + t\mathbf e_i)\\
= f(\mathbf x) + t[(\mathbf x - \mathbf c)^TA\mathbf e_i + \mathbf e_i^T A(\mathbf x - \mathbf c)] + t^2 \mathbf e_i^T A \mathbf e_i.
$$
Notably, we have
$$
[(\mathbf x - \mathbf c)^TA\mathbf e_i]^T = \mathbf e_i^T A^T(\mathbf x - \mathbf c)
$$
and any scalar is equal to its own transpose.  So, the above simplifies to 
$$
f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf e_i) = 
f(\mathbf x) + t[\mathbf e_i^T (A + A^T)(\mathbf x - \mathbf c)] + t^2 \mathbf e_i^T A \mathbf e_i.
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you are getting the term  $te_i(A+A^T) (x-c)$? I am getting $t (e_i^TA(x-c)+(x-c)^T Ae_i)$. Are these two equal?

Comment: Yes, they are equal.  What I tried to communicate in my answer is that
$$
t(e_i^TA(x-c) + (x-c)^TAe_i) = \\
t(e_i^TA(x-c) + e_i^TA^T(x-c)) =\\
te_i(A + A^T)(x-c)
$$

Comment: I did forget the transpose on the left side a few times; maybe that confused you.  The current version is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Final quation.  Should there be a transpose on $e_i$ in the last equation?

Comment: Yes there should be